# SQL cursor infinite even with WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO BREAK

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

My sql code with C is simple:

```
...
memset(statement, '\0', sizeof(statement));
sprintf(statement, sizeof(statement), "select col1, col2 from table1");

EXEC SQL PREPARE SEL_INSTR FROM :statement;
EXEC SQL DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SEL_INSTR;
EXEC SQL OPEN MY_CURSOR;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;
...

while(1){
   EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :dt1, :dt2;
   current_row++;
}

EXEC SQL CLOSE MY_CURSOR;

...
```

In my tableI have 4 rows od data. What is strange is even with using DO BREAK my loop continues indefinitely. Am I missing some instruction for sql?

Comment: It has been a long time since I worked with embedded SQL but I think you are getting the SQL and C code mixed up.  The break on SQL will just exit to the C code not exit the while loop in the C code.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks Hogam, but I did this statement based on oracle documentation. It says to break a loop use this statement: "EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO BREAK;"

Comment: @Hogan https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/PC_22/ch03a.htm

Comment: hmmm... based on the doc try changing the`while` to a `for`

Comment: @Hogan Unbelievable, but this solves the problem. Honestly, I don't know why. Thanks Hogan.

Comment: That makes sense -- remember what embedded SQL has to do -- it has to do.  It has to pre-process your C program and change it to something that performs the actions.  If their parser only looks for `for(;;)` then a `while(1)` won't work.

Comment: So this is actually not really C. Please remove the C tag.

Comment: The [11gR2 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_09err.htm#sthref1288) seem to show the OP's pattern with the DO BREAK before a while loop; but the doc the OP linked to (which is from Oracle 7!?) has a `while` example with the `WHENEVER` inside the loop. I don't see anything suggesting that should be necessary though. Which version are you using?